Docker APIClient: port from ssh/config
Let's say I have a remote server admin@10.10.10.10:1234. In my ~/.ssh/config I have this:
remote_server:
HostName: 10.10.10.10
User: admin
Port: 1234

I try to establish connection with Docker APIClient:
docker.APIClient('ssh://remote_server')

but it tries to connect to port 22 instead of 1234. It successfully parses HostName and User, but doesn't take into account the port from config file. Does anybody know the reason? And is it possible to fix it? Workaround like
docker.APIClient('ssh://remote_server:1234')

is not good in my case. I want to be able to use only the placeholder from config.

Ok, I found the reason, why it's happening. When url, passed to the APIClient, starts with "ssh://", SSHHTTPAdapter is being called. This class has a method _create_paramiko_client, which parses "~/.ssh/config". And it adds some params from this configs to the dictionary self.ssh_params. Regarding the port, there is this statement:
if base_url.port is None and 'port' in host_config:

But base_url.port by default is 22, so it's never None. That's why this record in config file is ignored. So, solution may be a monkeypatching the method _create_paramiko_client, like it was suggested for similar purpose here.
